# How to pick the highest value in each category in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api, tableau-desktop, avmutableaudiomixinputparameters

I have to pick the highest value from col 2 in relation col 1 using Tableau. The data is as follows

```
col 1       col 2
category 1   5
category 2   6
category 1   4
category 1   3
category 2   10
category 1   1
category 2   3
```

The desired solution is

```
col 1       col 2
category 1   5
category 2   10
```

I tried using the fixed aong with max function but in this case it outputs boolean value which I do not need. Could someone help me!

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Drag col 1 in the rows shelf.

Double click col 2.

Right-Click col 2 --> measure --> Maximum

(Eventually) Drag Max(col 2) from row shel to Text Mark

EDIT

See the screenshot as an example.
[To be noted that you can achieve this simple result with differnt ways/clicks]

[image]

BTW: are you familiar with dimensions and measures? it seems to me that you may need some basics training/study in order to get familiar with Tableau basics.

You may start from here: https://www.tableau.com/en-gb/learn/training/20212

Comment: I tried your solution, but it outputs the value 1 for all the values. Not the maximum value!

Comment: I've added a screenshot to the answer, please check it and consider to go through some basic training.